# Reading operations on hadoop and consistency level

Tags: hadoop, hbase, consistency

I am setting up distributed HBase on HDFS and I trying to understand behavior of the system during read operations.

This is how I understand high level steps of the read operation.

1. Client connects to NameNode to get list of DataNodes which contain replicas of the rows that he interested in.
2. From here Client caches list of DataNodes and start talking to chosen DataNode directly until it needs some other rows from other DataNode, in which case it asks NameNode again.

My questions are as follows:

1. Who chooses the best replica DataNode to contact? How Client chooses "closest" replica? Does NameNode return list of relative DataNodes in a sorted order ?
2. What are the scenarios(if any) when Client switches to another DataNode that has requested rows? For example if one of the DataNode becomes overloaded/slow can the client library figure out to contact another DataNode from the list returned by the NameNode?
3. Is there a possibility of getting stale data from one of the replicas? For example client acquired list of DataNodes and starts reading from one of them. In the mean time there is a write request coming from another client to NameNode. We have dfs.replication == 3 and dfs.replication.min = 2. NameNode consider write successful after flushing to disk on 2 out of 3 nodes, while first client is reading from the 3rd node and doesn't know (yet) that there is another write that has been committed ?
4. Hadoop maintains the same reading policy when supporting HBase?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Who chooses the best replica DataNode to contact? How Client chooses "closest" replica? Does NameNode return list of relative DataNodes in a sorted order ?

The client is the one that decides who best to contact. It picks them in this order:

1. The file is on the same machine. In this case (if properly configured) it will short circuit the DataNode and go directly to the file as an optimization.
2. The file is in the same rack (if rack awareness is configured).
3. The file is somewhere else.

> What are the scenarios(if any) when Client switches to another DataNode that has requested rows? For example if one of the DataNode becomes overloaded/slow can the client library figure out to contact another DataNode from the list returned by the NameNode?

It's not that smart. It'll switch if it thinks the DataNode is down (meaning it times out) but in not any other situation that I know of. I believe that it will just go to the next one in the list, but it might contact the NameNode again-- I'm not 100% sure.

> Is there a possibility of getting stale data from one of the replicas? For example client acquired list of DataNodes and starts reading from one of them. In the mean time there is a write request coming from another client to NameNode. We have dfs.replication == 3 and dfs.replication.min = 2. NameNode consider write successful after flushing to disk on 2 out of 3 nodes, while first client is reading from the 3rd node and doesn't know (yet) that there is another write that has been committed ?

Stale data is possible, but not in the situation you describe. Files are write-once and immutable (other than append, but don't append if you don't have to). The NameNode won't tell you the file is there until it is completely written. In the case of append, shame on you then. The behavior of reading from an actively-being-appended-to file on a local filesystem is unpredictable as well. You should expect the same in HDFS.

One way stale data could happen is if you retrieve your list of block locations and the NameNode decides to migrate all three of them at once before you access it. I don't know what would happen there. In the 5 years of using Hadoop, I've never had this be a problem. Even when running the balancer at the same time as doing stuff.

> Hadoop maintains the same reading policy when supporting HBase?

HBase is not treated special by HDFS. There is some talk about u[sing a custom block placement strategy with HBase](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-4755) to get better data locality, but that's in the weeds.